# Custom layout for listView in MvvmCross

Tags: mvvmcross

I have one viewModel in my MvvmCross PCL ,which contain a **list of MyClass**.
and this MyClass contain one member of int type called **ResponseId**.
I want to create a custom layout for listView,where each listItem contain different control(eg. ratingBar,RadioButton etc) for ResponseId depending on the value of the ResponseId of that listItem.
How can I design a layout for listItem?

```
  [Activity(Label = "View for MetricsByCat2ViewModel")]
  public class MetricsByCat2View : MvxActivity
 {
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MetricsByCat2View);
    }

    protected override void OnViewModelSet()
    {
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.MetricsByCat2View);


        var list = FindViewById<MvxListView>(Resource.Id.TheListView);
        TextView tv = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv);
        try
        {
            list.Adapter = new CustomAdapter(this as IMvxAndroidBindingContext, 
            BindingContext as IMvxAndroidBindingContext);


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            tv.Text = e.Message;
        }
    }

    public class CustomAdapter : MvxAdapter
    {
        public CustomAdapter(IMvxAndroidBindingContext context, 
         IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext)
            : base((Android.Content.Context)context, bindingContext)
        {

        }

        public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
        {
            var item = GetRawItem(position);
            if (item is StarRating)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }

        public override int ViewTypeCount
        {
            get { return 2; }
        }

        protected override View GetBindableView(View convertView, object source, 
                                                   int templateId)
        {
            if (source is StarRating)
                templateId = Resource.Layout.item_met2;
            // else if (source is Dog)
            //     templateId = Resource.Layout.ListItem_Dog;

            return base.GetBindableView(convertView, source, templateId);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I am referring same example as you told @Stuart Sir. https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Working%20With%20Collections

Answer (score 4):

There is a sample of polymorphic lists in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Working%20With%20Collections - this uses a custom adapter like:

```
    public class CustomAdapter : MvxAdapter
    {
        public CustomAdapter(Context context, IMvxAndroidBindingContext bindingContext)
            : base(context, bindingContext)
        {
        }

        public override int GetItemViewType(int position)
        {
            var item = GetRawItem(position);
            if (item is Kitten)
                return 0;
            return 1;
        }

        public override int ViewTypeCount
        {
            get { return 2; }
        }

        protected override View GetBindableView(View convertView, object source, int templateId)
        {
            if (source is Kitten)
                templateId = Resource.Layout.ListItem_Kitten;
            else if (source is Dog)
                templateId = Resource.Layout.ListItem_Dog;

            return base.GetBindableView(convertView, source, templateId);
        }
    }
```

In your app, you will need to do something similar - but doing the view selection using the `ResponseId` rather than the source Type.

Comment: But it is giving error at a line of   list.Adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, (IMvxAndroidBindingContext)BindingContext);  And the error is   cannot convert from 'Cognition.IForIndia.Droid.Views to Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.BindingContext.IMvxAndroidBindingContext

Comment: I have solved that problem by replacing  list.Adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,IMvxAndroidBindingContext)BindingContext);         with list.Adapter = new CustomAdapter(this as IMvxAndroidBindingContext, BindingContext as IMvxAndroidBindingContext);     But now it is displaying nothing

Comment: Please try to provide more information in your questions, and please try to avoid providing partial code snippets in comments. It's generally easier to understand questions where you include the code that is causing the problem. Providing a complete working code makes things especially easy for answerers. When writing questions or comments, it may help if you imagine you were the one answering the questions - want info would help you answer? For some more tips, see http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx